# How to combine and output two string arrays?

Tags: java, arrays

```
String[] row = {"Below 0 degrees", "From 0 to 32", "From 33 to 50", "From 51 to 60", "From 61 to 70", "From 71 to 90", "Above 90" };
String[] suit = {"Very cold", "Cold", " Mild", "Very mild", "Warm", "Very warm", "Hot" };
```

I have tried setup in an array, how I do I continue now?

My desired output:

> Below 0 degrees = Very cold
>
> From 0 to 32 = Cold
>
> From 33 to 50 = Mild
>
> From 51 to 60 = Very mild
>
> From 61 to 70 = Warm
>
> From 71 to 90 = Very warm
>
> Above 90 = Hot

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. Please show your code, and ask as specific a question as possible. Please don't ask us for code either but rather to answer questions.

Comment: To produce the output that you've mentioned, try this: `for(int i = 0;i<7;i++){System.out.println(row[i] + " =  " + suit[i]);}`, make sure both arrays have a length of `7`.

Comment: Or you could use a hash.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, I think this is what you're trying to do:

```
String[] row = {"Below 0 degrees", "From 0 to 32", "From 33 to 50", "From 51 to 60", "From 61 to 70", "From 71 to 90", "Above 90" }; 
String[] suit = {"Very cold", "Cold", " Mild", "Very mild", "Warm", "Very warm", "Hot" };

for(int i=0; i<row.length;i++) {
    System.out.println(row[i] + "=" + suit[i]);
    System.out.println();
}
```

Or perhaps a map would work even better if `row` and `suit` are so linked:

```
Map<String, String> rowSuit = new LinkedHashMap<>();

rowSuit.put("Below 0 Degrees", "Very Cold");
rowSuit.put("From 0 to 32", "Cold");
...

for(Entry<String, String> e : rowSuit.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(e.getKey() + "=" + e.getValue());
    System.out.println();
}
```